# How to prevent timestamp fields to update its value when updating a record

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Lets say I enter this way a record

```
"insert into table (value,time) VALUES ('4',NOW())"
```

And this is how I update a value

```
"update table set value = '5' WHERE id = '1'"
```

The problem is that with the last query, the time value gets updated with the current_timestamp again, so the time is wrong.

How can I prevent this? (I want time's value to remain the current_timestamp when was inserted, not updated)

PD: I tried to remove the value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from the row using sqlBuddy but it gets applied again, like if no changes where saved..

Comment: did you try creating `time` and `date` as a field type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply add in the current value of the field in your update query like this:

```
update table set value = '5', timestamp_value = timestamp_value WHERE id = '1'
```

Comment: I don't know if its the best solution, but in this case was the easiest for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just make the field a DateTime field with a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. So it will be set upon creation of a new record but updated only when you want.

Comment: To change your table, create a new column time2, they will all have the current date. Then copy previous time value to time2, then remove time column, then rename time2 to time.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the default value set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

This should ease your pain.

Answer (score -1):

TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP remove on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attribute.

It works on PhpmyAdmin.